The method of calculating and using the various components of the StochRSI indicator in an expert
I need the formula for calculating the StochRSI indicator. Actually, I want to use K and D values ​​in an expert and I want to use the values ​​of this indicator as desired. Please help me in this regard. Thank you for your kindness and response.
I found the following formula by searching. Of course, I could not write the code for it.
your text// -- parameters:
your textlengthRSI : 10 //RSI period
your textlengthStoch : 10 //Stochastic period
your textsmoothK : 10 //Smooth signal of stochastic RSI
your textsmoothD : 3 //Smooth signal of smoothed stochastic RSI
your textmyRSI : RSIlengthRSI
your textMinRSI : lowestlengthStoch
your textMaxRSI : highestlengthStoch
your textStochRSI: (myRSI-MinRSI) / (MaxRSI-MinRSI)
your textK :averagesmoothK*100
your textD : averagesmoothD
your textreturn K as "K%", D as "D%"
